# AWS CLI: Retrieve list of running EC2 instance types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying a quick way to list/output all instances type running in my environment. Nothing else just a list of those `InstanceType`.

I can easily get them on the console but it's a bit time consuming.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [aws ec2 describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) ?

Comment: ...together either --query --filter and jq commandline tool you can do many things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS CLI -

`aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1 --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceType' --output text | sort | uniq`

In AWS web console - You can also use [AWS Config -> Advanced queries ->
Query editor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/querying-AWS-resources.html) as shown below. Output can be exported as json or csv. Also have [aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/query-using-sql-editor-cli.html) for this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Personally I use [Steampipe](https://hub.steampipe.io/plugins/turbot/aws/tables/aws_ec2_instance) to query AWS (and other cloud) resources using SQL from my terminal. Per your question, I've also limited resources to those "running":

```
select
  instance_type,
  count(*)
from
  aws_ec2_instance
where
  instance_state = 'running'
group by
  instance_type
order by
  count
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this maybe help you:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceType]" \
--output json
```